# Regx Extract template tags {{..}} from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract squiggly bracketed template tags from a string. For example:

```
var str="Hello {{user}}, your reference is {{ref}}"
```

I would like a to extract the tags in-between the {{..}} into an array. For example:

```
["user","ref"]
```

How can i do this, for example with a Regx - I would need to ignore any whitespace in-side the brackets for example {{ user}} would need to return "user"

Comment: Maybe something like `{{\s*(\w*)\s*}}`, extract group 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var found = [],          // an array to collect the strings that are found
    rxp = /{{([^}]+)}}/g,
    str = "Hello {{user}}, your reference is {{ref}} - testing {one} braces. Testing {{uncomplete} braces.",
    curMatch;

while( curMatch = rxp.exec( str ) ) {
    found.push( curMatch[1] );
}

console.log( found );    // ["user", "ref"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: found.push( curMatch[1],trim() ) - Solves the unwanted white-space if tags are typed with spaces. Nice.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that, feel free to suggest an edit, I will approve it. Nice catch!

Comment: `[^}}]+` is same as `[^}]+`, and also your regex will catch things like `{{x}` as well ( This is most unlikely be a case )

Comment: @CodeManiac you are right, it was an oversight. I updated `rxp` above to fix that. Thanks for your input.